# AppleScript to paste clipboard into current application

Tags: applescript, paste, text-formatting

I thought this would be simple...

I want an AppleScript that launches Plain Clip and then pastes the clipboard into the current document where the cursor is. My script launches Plain Clip (a format-clearing app that doesn't steal focus), but it doesn't paste the new clipboard. Any ideas?

```
tell application "Plain Clip" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to tell (name of application processes whose frontmost is true) to keystroke "v" using {command down}
```

Comment: yep, no dice...I'll update the code though

Comment: I realized later that `{}` seems to be the notation for a list of keys. So I guess it would just be optional in this case. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're stripping the clipboard down to plaintext anyway, you could perhaps finish by scripting the keyboard rather than scripting Plain Clip.

```
do shell script "pbpaste |textutil -convert txt -stdin -stdout -encoding 30 |pbcopy"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (the clipboard)
```

p.s. that first line does the same thing that Plain Clip does.
p.p.s. scripting System Events requires [access for assistive devices](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html) to be on.

Comment: I have System Events type out the clipboard for me all the time, into text fields that don't allow pasting. For example, I have long, random-character passwords for some encrypted disk images stored in a password manager, but DiskImageMounter doesn't allow pasting.

Comment: This works within the AppleScript editor if I click Run. However, I've set a keyboard shortcut to run this, and when I press the shortcut, weird things happen. It doesn't paste the clipboard. Furthermore, I want it to remove leading/trailing spaces/tabs from each line, as well as blank lines and invisible control characters, like Plain Clip does. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: If you use this, you have to be careful not to press any modifier keys while the clipboard is being typed out.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your script and it worked fine for me. Which OS are you using?

Another option is to use have AppleScript run a shell script accessing PlainClip's command line option:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (name of application processes whose frontmost is true) to do shell script "'/Applications/Plain Clip.app/pc' -v"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved my problem:

```
delay 0.2
do shell script "'/Applications/Plain Clip.app/pc' -w -l -m -i -s -a -v"
```

Thanks guys.